# Dynamically adding different components with events in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to create a list of similar components that will be added automatically.

Something like this: [image: communication between components]

Dynamic component rendering with Vue is easy, but there is a problem in communication between parent and child in these components.
In the child is a button and when a user clicks on it, the counter in the parent should change.

Something like this example:

```js
const Reusable = {
  template: '<div>{{ name }} {{ bar }}<button @click="doClick">Click</button></div>',
  
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  methods: {
    doClick() {
        console.log("clicked");
      this.$emit("clicked");
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      bar: 'Bar'
    }
  }
}

const App = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    items: [],
    value: 0,
  },
  
  methods: {
    onClick() { //I want to run this method 
      console.log("onClick method");
      this.value = this.value + 1;
    },
    addComponent () {
      const renderComponent = {
        render (h) {         
          return h(Reusable, {
            class: ['foo'],
            
            props: { 
              name: 'Foo'
            },
            on: {
                clicked() {
                console.log("on clicked in Reusable");
                this.onClick(); //why this method cannot be called?

              },
            },
/*          events: {
              clicked: this.onClick()
            } */
          })
        }
      }
      
      this.items.push(renderComponent)      
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#app {
  padding: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/milligram/1.3.0/milligram.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <component v-for="item in items" ref="itemRefs" :is="item" :key="item.name"></component>
  <div> {{value}} </div>
  <button @click="addComponent">Add Component</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the `$emit` altogether and use `@click.native="value++"`:

```js
const Reusable = {
  template: '<div>{{ name }} {{ bar }}<button @click="doClick">Click</button></div>',

  props: {
    name: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  methods: {
    doClick() {
      console.log("clicked");
      this.bar = 'Baz';
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      bar: 'Bar'
    }
  }
}

const App = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    items: [],
    value: 0,
  },

  methods: {
    addComponent() {
      const renderComponent = {
        render(h) {
          return h(Reusable, {
            class: ['foo'],

            props: {
              name: 'Foo'
            },
          })
        }
      }

      this.items.push(renderComponent)
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#app {
  padding: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/milligram/1.3.0/milligram.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <component v-for="item in items" ref="itemRefs" :is="item" :key="item.name" @click.native="value++"></component>
  <div> {{value}} </div>
  <button @click="addComponent">Add Component</button>
</div>
```

Comment: that would be a good, but what if I want to add something more to the method `doClick`
(maybe some more logic)

Comment: It would still work, I've updated my snippet so `doClick` changes `Bar` to `Baz`.